# Printing JSON object data to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, object

I am trying to write an html code that shows current version of my software product (something like **"v1.0.0"**) with printing data from a JSON file.

In my server there is a JSON file that stores the my software product version data like below (let's say the location is https://testsite.com/myproductversion.json):

```
{
  "Name": "MyProduct",
  "MajorVersion": "1",
  "MinorVersion" : "0",
  "MaintenanceVersion" : "0"
}
```

Is it possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not difficult at all. Use ajax to get the json and match each property to an element to insert the text into. Both steps are easy to research

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57939053/convert-json-object-to-html-string

Comment: Hi thank you for the quick answer. I am newbie, sorry. Is it possible to make it with HTML? I will use this html code in Wordpress text editor. Where will I use the ajax in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

```js
fetch('/myproductversion.json').then(res => res.json())
.then(({ MajorVersion, MinorVersion, MaintenanceVersion }) => {
  let version = `v${MajorVersion}.${MinorVersion}.${MaintenanceVersion}`;
  $('.my-version-goes-here').html(version);
}).catch(console.error);
```

Just use fetch to make a request for the data.

Comment: Hi thank you for the quick answer. Is it possible to make it with HTML? I will use this html code in Wordpress text editor. Thank you for your help....

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understand your question right.
One of many ways is to use jquery/js.

Here is a small snippet to give you an example

```js
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });
 
  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the quick answer. Is it possible to make it with HTML? I will use this html code in Wordpress text editor. Thank you for your help....