# How to display a STRING of ejs code saved in a variable on another ejs template?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

**My objective** is to have a page on which I would like to display some information via ejs in a specified div. There would be some buttons to change the way and/or the displayed information.

I've already created the button to display a dummy text. Now I would like to display  some different template already stored as a string in my DB.

So I have this first ejs file, from where the user should be able to select another part of displayed code via some button. The buttons use a JS script to display the code with an `.append()`. I use

```
<%- JSON.stringify(stringOfCode)%>
```

to display my template. My problem is that the code is displayed within some quotation marks and that the ejs inside the `stringOfCode` is not working:

```
"
TEST TEMPLATE
Email Address : <%= user.email %>
First Name : <%= user.firstName %>
Last Name : <%= user.lastName %>
"
```

How can I solve this ?
Or is there a better suited solution for what I want to do ?

**EDIT**

In my search of a solution, I've tried this :
I put the content of `stringOfCode` into a new ejs file called *test0*
In my script, I used this:

```js
     wrapper.append('<div class="container canvas" id="toCan"> Test 1  <%- include('test0'); %>   </div>');
```

the result is that my button stopped working. I suppose this cause some kind of conflict when rendering the *test0*. Simply putting `<%- include('test0'); %>` works fine on its own, but that not what I'm aiming for

Comment: sounds like you need a html string rather than javascript string. See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57939053/convert-json-object-to-html-string

Comment: My _stringOfCode_ look like : `<h1>TEST TEMPLATE</h1><div class="container"><hr><ul> Email Address : <%= user.email %></ul><ul> First Name : <%= user.firstName %></ul><ul> Last Name : <%= user.lastName %></ul><hr></div>`, like in the exemple you suggested. I would like the snippets like `<%= user.firstName %>` in the _stringOfCode_ to fully work as EJS and not plain test ..